# no match for call to '(QPalette)()' Qt4 in Linux

Tags: linux, qt

When I compiled an example code in **QtCreator3.3.2** with **Qt4.8.6** in **Ubuntu14.04**, this following error occurred:

```
videowidget.cpp:19: error: no match for call to '(QPalette) ()'
     palette = palette();
                       ^
```

in this snippet:

```
VideoWidget::VideoWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent),surface(0)
{   
    setAutoFillBackground(false);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground,true);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen,true);

    palette = this->palette();//here's the error 
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Background,Qt::black);
    setPalette(palette);
    setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding,QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);
    surface = new VideoWidgetSurface(this);
}
```

I looked up `QPlalette` class and `QWidget` class in Qt Assistant and manual of `QWidget` says:

> Access functions:
>
> const QPalette & palette () const
>
> void setPalette ( const QPalette & )

which seems to me that `QWidget` has `palette()` function and so `VideoWidget` will definitely have it. But such error comes out. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You hide `palette()` when you declare a variable with the same name. Use some other name, for example:

```
QPalette myPalette = palette();
```

In your snippet you have another working solution using `this`:

```
QPalette palette = this->palette();
```